# Scientific way to describe "over linear growth"

Tags: word-usage, expressions, phrase-usage, science

I am aware that typically we use "linear" growth or "exponential" growth to describe certain trending, which seems very standard and scientific.

But on the other hand, what is a proper and scientific way to describe a trending that is "over" linear (faster than linear), but apparently not yet exponential? Can I simply say "over linear"? Thanks.

For instance:

```
The processing time grows over linearly w.r.t. the number of loop iterations.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Superlinear

(mathematics) Describing a function that eventually grows faster than any linear one

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/superlinear